# How to Put Border Radius in a Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to Do something like BorderRadius for a container, kind of Lost how to go about it as i am getting this Error

https://i.postimg.cc/nMbY0vyx/Screenshot-1664289375.png

How do i go about it? Starting out Flutter some days ago. I need some help with it. Source code looks like this :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TransactionDetails {
  String? avatar;
  String? name;
  String? date;
  String? amount;

  TransactionDetails({
    this.avatar,
    this.name,
    this.date,
    this.amount,
  });

  TransactionDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    avatar = json['avatar'];
    name = json['name'];
    date = json['date'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['avatar'] = avatar;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['date'] = date;
    data['amount'] = amount;
    return data;
  }
}

Future<List<TransactionDetails>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
    return result.map((e) => TransactionDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "My Bank",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 27),
                onPressed: () {})
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))), // from here 
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$5200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$1200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Text(
                "Recent Transactions",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
                    future: fetchAlbum(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      snapshot.data![index].avatar.toString()),
                                ),
                                title:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                                trailing: Text(
                                    snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].date.toString()),
                              );
                            });
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                      }
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }))
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

Like I said, i am fairly new to this,I need some Clarification here.

Answer (score 0):

The error refers, you can use either `color` or `decoration` on Container. `BoxDecoration` has a color parameter that can be used on Container color.

> The `color` and `decoration` arguments cannot both be supplied, since it would potentially result in the decoration drawing over the background
> color. To supply a decoration with a color, use `decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)`.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.green,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(20),
    ),
  ), 
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
  width: 319,
  height: 100,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: const Text(
```

More about [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [Container/color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/color.html)

Comment: Still throws the same Error. What do i change it to?

Comment: try `flutter clean` and save the file, rebuild again

Comment: the error persits @Yeasin

Comment: it might be coming from different place where you’ve done this same thing, if it is the only widget, try restarting the ide

Comment: i use Visual Studio Code'

Comment: close and open again.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.green, // if you using decoration color should be include in decoration
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))), // 
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                width: 319,
                height: 100,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text(
                  '\$5200.00',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
```

Comment: Still throws the same Error. What do i change it to?

Comment: try rebuilding because that error should be fixed with that.

Comment: did you move color into boxDecoration?

Comment: nah. I did as you said, it just did not work.

Comment: what is the error saying? same error?

Comment: yes. did flutter clean, error is stil same when i build again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the color parameter and the decoration parameter together.

it either you have this

```dart
  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))), // from here 
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
```

but considering your case where you have to also use a box decoration, you'd have to remove the color property and place it in the decoration like this

```dart
  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius:   BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))), // from here 
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
```

ensure you remove the previous color property